# Uninstall 4.7 .dotnet framework and install 4.6.1 on windows server 2016 win10

Tags: .net, windows, windows-10

We have a windows server 2016 win 10 machine that has dot net framework 4.7 installed. Now i have a need to install 4.6.1 for an application that uses Arcfm desktop and as per their doc their target framework has to be fixed 4.6.1.

http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.6.1a/DesktopSDK/webframe.html

Desktop ArcFM customizations in .NET must target .NET Framework 4.6.1. We cannot assure correct behavior of ArcFM Objects in later versions of the .NET Framework because the later frameworks run in their own stack.

Is there a way to uninstall 4.7 on win10 and install 4.6.1? Any help or suggestions here will be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: But then there are failures in the builds complaining about 4.6.1 not found.

Comment: The short answer is no.  You can not uninstall 4.7.x from windows 10, as it is a system component.  Since all .net frameworks 4.x share the same installation, it is not possible to really install 4.6.1 (which is no longer supported btw) on Windows 10.  The installation, if it runs, would/should detect you already have 4.7.x installed and just silently continue.

Comment: I would contact that company's support.  The oldest still supported version of windows is 2008R2 (which even this is EOL as of January 2020), and that came with 4.6.2.

Comment: Thanks Robert. So you mean to say, i can still go with win 7 or win 8 with 4.6.1 framework but at our own risk since 4.6.1 support will end officially by windows by jan 2020?